# MySQL Clustering issues in Windows platform

Tags: mysql, windows, cluster-computing, mysql-cluster

i have 2 windows machines

1) 192.168.168.01

2) 192.168.168.02

I want to use these two for configure clustering,

mySQL version: mysql-cluster-gpl-noinstall-7.1.3-win32

here is my config.ini:

> > [ndbd default]
>
> NoOfReplicas=1
>
> DataDir=D:\ProgramFiles\mysqlcluster\datanode\mysql\bin\cluster-data
>
> DataMemory=80M
>
> IndexMemory=18M
>
> [TCP DEFAULT]
>
> [ndb_mgmd]
>     nodeid=1
>     HostName=192.168.168.01 
>    DataDir=C:\mysql\mysql-cluster
>
> [ndbd] 
>    nodeid=2
>    HostName=192.168.168.02
>    datadir=D:\Program
>    Files\mysqlcluster\datanode\mysql\cluster-data

but when i try to run ndb_mgmd.exe, encounter this error:

> C:\mysql\bin>ndb_mgmd.exe --config-file="c:\mysql\bin\config.ini"
>   --configdir="C:\mysql\mysql-cluster"  MySQL Cluster Management Server mysql-5.5.19 ndb-7.2.4  2012-02-22 03:09:15 [MgmtSrvr] ERROR -- Could
>   not determine which nodeid to use for this node. Specify it with
>   --ndb-  nodeid= on command line

pls help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check , your config.ini file should be like this:-

```
[ndbd default]
datadir=C:\Users\user\my_cluster\ndb_data
noofreplicas=1

[ndb_mgmd]
hostname=127.0.0.1
datadir=C:\Users\user\my_cluster\ndb_data
NodeId=1

[ndbd]
datadir=C:\Users\user\my_cluster\mysqld_data\mysql
hostname=127.0.0.1
NodeId=3

[mysqld]
NodeId=50
```

Also, check your query, it should be like this:-

```
start /B C:\Users\user\MySQL_Cluster\bin\ndb_mgmd -f conf\config.ini --initial --configdir=C:\Users\user\my_cluster\conf
```

my_cluster is the folder where I want to create the cluster data.